# How to update jQuery-UI progress bar with AJAXcall (files scan)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to hash all the files in a specific folder with AJAX and update the progress, meaning I don't want the AJAX to stop at the first reply. I searched online and I thing I found the right answer but it doesn't work.

My jQuery( mixed js):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#progress').progressbar();

document.getElementById('save').onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('save_log');
    var security = $('#save_security').val();

    div.innerHTML = '';

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", checkit.admin_ajax, false);

    xhr.onprogress = function(evt) {
        //var json = JSON.parse(e.currentTarget.responseText);
        //var percentComplete = ( json.currentFile * 100 ) / json.filesCount;  
        var progress = evt.currentTarget.responseText;

        $('#progress').progressbar("value", progress);   
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    }

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("action=checkit_scan_files&security=" + security);
};

});
```

and my php AJAX

```
        $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    $iterator->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

    $fi = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $iterator );

    $files = array(); 
    $i = 1;
    $size = $this->get_files_count();

    foreach ($fi as $file) {

        if ( !$file->isDir() ) { 
            $files[$i]['md5'] = md5_file( $file->getPathname() ); 
            $files[$i]['path'] = $file->getPathname();

            $progress = ($i * 100) / $size;
            $i++;

            echo intval( $progress );
        }

    }
```

Comment: what do you get if console.log(evt.currentTarget.responseText)

Comment: And what sort of third party progressbar are you using?

Comment: I'm getting the result in one time : 000000111111222222233333444444555555666677777. I use jquery ui.

Comment: Jquey ui docs say: $('#progress').progressbar({"value": progress}). Can it be the issue? And i noticed you initialize progressbar twice.